# Creating modules in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, reflection, module, .net-assembly

I am playing with reflections in C# and encountered the concepts of Assembly and Module.

An assembly contains at least one module which is created automatically when a new assembly is created.

Anyway you can create a new module only from the command line.

I am just wondering why in Visual Studio it is not possible to create a new module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features in Visual Studio are driven by where they think the priorities lie, and the amount of resources they can throw on any given feature.  The notion that VS should make modules (i.e., a file of extension 'netmodule') is probably really far down the list of priorities if it exists at all.  One rationale for saying that is 'who needs it?'  And the answer is just about nobody.

The CLR's smallest unit of deployment is an 'assembly' and that's what VS produces.  Of course it combines modules along the way (you might even be able to find some in the 'obj' folder after a build); but modules are never created with the intent of having modules as a persistent result.  The only useful thing you can do with a module is to pack it inside an assembly, and VS already does this.

I'm thinking that handles about 99% of the use cases.  For use cases that are more exotic, there's the command line option which you have referred to.